# Implementing mocked test cases for a Result Row

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I've implemented an interface named `ResultRow`. This Interface has some virtual functions for getting a value by passing a field name (`getValue(const std::string& field) const`):

```
class ResultRow
{
    public:

        virtual ~ResultRow();

        virtual std::string operator[] (const std::string& field) const = 0;
        virtual std::string getValue(const std::string& field) const = 0;
        virtual int getValueInt(const std::string& field) const = 0;
};
```

A concrete class of this interface is ResultRowDb, which acts like a wrapper for a pqxx::tuple. getValue(const std::string& field) calls pqxx::tuple[field].

This interface was implemented for using a mocked ResultRow for the gTests.

At first I will make some basic mock tests like:
`MockedResultRow....WillOnce(Return(valueFieldA)).WillOnce(Return(valueFieldB))` and so on.

But I'm not sure how to implement the further test cases.
Additionally I want to check the correct selection of the field's value. This means, check if the field name exists in the result row and so on...

My thought is to implementing two different test cases:
The first one ist the mocked test above, and the second one is a new concrete class of a `ResultRow` for test purposes `ResultRowTest`.
I will set the expected key value-pairs with a `public` function and run the "normal" worker function by passing the `ResultRowTest` to it.

Is this a good solution? Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Please show your tests. You try to explain code in text, which doesn't work out that well and is only confusing.

Comment: I havn't any tests yet. I want to know if it is good practise to split the tests into two different parts. Part one using a gMock and the second one by implementing a concrete test class "ResultRowTest" for a near "live" test.

Comment: You usually want several layers of tests. Unit tests are at the lowest layer, where you test small chunks of code. Than you could for example test your whole application with mocked dependencies to other libraries and test your application in real environment. The way you test is only dependent on your project and its requirements.

Comment: Why do think you need to implement new class `ResultRowTest`? Normally you would create objects from class `ResultRowDb` to test this concrete implementation.

Comment: I'm not allowed to create pqxx::result objects by myself, because it's costructor is private. The class ResultRowDb wraps a pqxx::result. But you're right, i havn't created a ResultRowTest, instead i used a mocked class, which inherits from ResultRow.